# Minio - how to generate read-only access for mirroring

Tags: minio

Given I have a PRIMARY server and a REPLICA.
When I need to run a MIRROR server I want for security reasons to have READ-ONLY ACCESS

Q: How to generate a second pair of access key and secret key for read-only access?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Create a new IAM user in the AWS Console. Give it the S3 Read Only access policy.

Comment: I think you didn't read. It's about Minio, not AWS :) Minio is self hosted version of S3.

Comment: Then you shouldn't tag this with Amazon S3. The Minio quickstart guide appears to cover this - search https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-multi-user-quickstart-guide.html for `readonly`.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for totally different keywords, maybe too technical.

Comment: `minio read only` is how I got there. FYI :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution looks to be there, I looked for different keywords, so I didn't find it before.

https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-multi-user-quickstart-guide.html

When this error happened:

```
<ERROR> Unable to update the server. The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
```

I had to upgrade Minio to at least RELEASE.2019-09-11T19-53-16Z.